# Animation independent of frame rate

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, physics, game-physics

To make animation independent of frame rate, is it necessary to multiply the delta value by both velocity and acceleration?

```
// Multiply both acceleration and velocity by delta?
vVelocity.x += vAcceleration.x * delta;
vVelocity.y += vAcceleration.y * delta;
position.x += vVelocity.x * delta;
position.y += vVelocity.y * delta;
```

Should I apply delta to the velocity only and not acceleration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your "delta" is the amount of time passed since last update:

**Short answer: yes.**

**Long answer:**

One way to check this sort of thing is to see if the units work out. It's not guaranteed, but usually if your units work out, then you've figured things correctly.

Velocity measures distance per unit time, and delta is time. So velocity times delta is (picking arbitrary units meters and seconds) `(m/s) * s = m`. So you can see that velocity times delta does create a distance, so that appears reasonable for position.

Acceleration measures velocity per unit time, that is, with the same units `(m/s)/s`. So, acceleration times delta is `((m/s)/s) * s = m/s`. Looks like a velocity to me. We're good!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is necessary to involve `delta` with both the velocity and the acceleration. They're both properties that are defined with respect to time (`m/s` for one, `m/s/s` for the other - units may vary), so `delta` should be used whenever they have to change non-instantaneously.